# Using spring boot 2.7.1 and swagger 2 dont use authentication on swagger-ui urls

Tags: spring-boot, security, swagger-2.0

I have this security config

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/prometheus", "/actuator/metrics/**", "/actuator/health/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();

    return http.build();
}
```

I want to let swagger url pass this config
using springboot 2.7.1 and swagger 2.9.2

But I always get

```
{
    "responseCode": "2401",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "timestamp": "2024-02-26T10:23:18.264+08:00"
}
```

my swagger config is :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(getPaths())
                .build();
    }

    private com.google.common.base.Predicate<String> getPaths() {
        return or(PathSelectors.ant("/v1/**"),
                or(PathSelectors.ant("/v2/**"),
                        PathSelectors.ant("/auth/v1/**")));
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties,
                                                                         WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment) {
        List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList();
        Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
        allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
        allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        String basePath = webEndpointProperties.getBasePath();
        EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(basePath);
        boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping = this.shouldRegisterLinksMapping(webEndpointProperties, environment,
                basePath);
        return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes,
                corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(), new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, basePath),
                shouldRegisterLinksMapping, null);
    }

    private boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping(WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment,
                                               String basePath) {
        return webEndpointProperties.getDiscovery().isEnabled() && (StringUtils.hasText(basePath)
                || ManagementPortType.get(environment).equals(ManagementPortType.DIFFERENT));
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs/**");
    }
```

and my custom security looks like

```
public class myFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String apiKey = request.getHeader(AUTH_METHOD);
        if (apiKey == null || apiKey.isEmpty()) {
            createErrorResponse(response, 401, HCResponseCodes.ACCESS_ERROR, INVALID_CREDS);
            return;
        }
```

I always end up in this condition.
what can i do to let swagger pass this test?